Is there a clever way to define the lift for the Dirichlet BC?
Consider the Poisson problem with Dirichlet boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 u(x) = f(x), \quad x \in \Omega  \\
u(x) = g(x), \quad x \in \partial\Omega
\end{equation}
To lift the Dirichlet boundary condition, one can introduce a function $ v(x) \in \Omega $ such that it satisfies the boundary condition exactly that is:
\begin{equation}
v(x) = g(x), \quad x \in \partial \Omega.
\end{equation}
Now, define a new unknown function  $w(x)$ by the relation:
\begin{equation}
u(x) = w(x) + v(x).
\end{equation}
Substituting $ u(x) = w(x) + v(x) $ into the original Poisson equation allows me to write an equation for $ w(x) $ with homogeneous boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 w(x) = f(x) - \nabla^2 v(x), \quad x \in \Omega \\
w(x) = 0, \quad x \in \partial \Omega.
\end{equation}
Now:
I want to solve this problem with FEM, so how does one go about constructing $v(x)$? There are infinity many $v(x)$ all of which satisfy the boundary condition but can still be whatever within the domain, is there a clever way to construct $v(x)$?

Note that often $v$ is chosen so that it is zero in all other mesh nodes than those on the boundary. Its laplacian is simple to implement by slicing the stiffness matrix integrated over the entire mesh.
